# Expo EAS build failure cannot load such file -- colored2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I am getting the following error when attempting to build the iOS version of my `expo` app using `eas build -p ios --local`:

```
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- colored2.
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  from /private/var/folders/yr/7xc177dn2cz107wsvzg573_m0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/c132d044-2136-499b-9471-1b0e11438b09/build/React/ios/Podfile:1
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  -------------------------------------------
[INSTALL_PODS]  >  require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  -------------------------------------------
```

This app runs locally just fine in ExpoGo but fails with the `eas` build both in the cloud and locally.

This issue began after running `expo upgrade` to update my project to expo v47.

I did a global search on my project (including node_modules folder) and didn't find any references to `colored2`

When I run `expo doctor` this is the output:

```
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.2
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.1
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
    (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Expected package @expo/prebuild-config@^5.0.5
Found invalid:
  @expo/prebuild-config@5.0.3
    (for more info, run: npm why @expo/prebuild-config)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by upgrading `cocoapods` on my computer by running `brew install cocoapods`. I then closed out of the terminal I was using and opened a new one.

[This post](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6659) helped me understand the issue